# How do I create a Clojure application with lein uberjar if I have a dependency in checkouts?

Tags: clojure, leiningen, uberjar

I have a Clojure application that is using a library which is symlinked from inside the "checkouts" directory.

This lets me work on both the app and the library at the same time. And lein knows how to compile and run the program without any problems.

But I want to make a standalone with lein uberjar, and it's complaining

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate mylib/core__init.class, mylib/core.clj or mylib/core.cljc on classpath.
```

I assume that that is because mylib isn't mentioned in my project.clj file. It isn't, precisely because I want to use the version of mylib symlinked inside "checkouts".

But the uberjar command doesn't seem to be able to see it.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Your `project.clj` should list `[mylib "0.1"]` in `project.clj` regardless of whether or not you are using the "checkouts" feature of lein.   Putting a symlink in `./checkouts` to point to a development version of mylib will override the Maven/Clojars lookup.  Maybe you should add your `project.clj` to the question to clarify this?

Comment: Another answer I saw on StackOverflow seemed to suggest that if I put [mylib "0.1"] in my projects.clj this would use the version from Clojars rather than my current / in-development version.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by installing `mylib` in your local repository (~/.m2/repository).

1. Run `lein install` in the dependent project to install it in your local repository.
2. Add the project to `:dependencies`: in `project.clj`:

   `[mylib "version"]`
3. Run `lein uberjar` in the main project.

The project will find the jar in your local repository.

/Edit

If you want to develop two libraries at the same time you can use a checkouts folder where checkouts contains a symlink to the dependent library.

```sh
mkdir checkouts
ln -nfs full-path-other-lib-dir full-path-checkouts-dir
```

Now changes in other-lib are immediately available in the main project.

See [https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/TUTORIAL.md#checkout-dependencies](the Leiningen checkouts documentation).

Comment: Thanks. But that is what I was hoping to avoid. I want a way of being able to develop and test my project and mylib at the same time, including testing the built product, without having to keep checking the library into a repo, giving it a version number etc.

Comment: Ah @interstar I updated the answer to help with that using checkouts.

Comment: And now I see you need features of the uberjar as well. Then I am not sure if that's possible. Interesting problem but I have no time now. You can ask on Clojurians Slack as well!

Answer (score 0):

OK, it appears that the "checkouts" feature of lein works with `lein test` and `lein run` but not with `lein uberjar`.

I added the following to the local source code of a lib `tupelo.core`:

```
(def dummy-sample-data "Bogus!")
```

In the consuming project `demo.core` we can access the new Var:

```
(ns demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(defn -main [& args]
  (println :foo-enter)
  (spyx dummy-sample-data)
  (println :foo-leave))
```

`lein run` produces:

```
:foo-enter
dummy-sample-data => "Bogus!"
:foo-leave
```

`project.clj` remains unchanged:

```
(defproject demo "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url  "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [
     [criterium "0.4.5"]
     [org.clojure/math.combinatorics "0.1.6"]
     [org.clojure/clojure "1.10.1"]
     [prismatic/schema "1.1.12"]
     [tupelo "0.9.201"]
   <snip>
```

where `"0.9.201"` is the latest version of `tupelo` on Clojars.  Checkouts looks like:

```
~/expr/demo > ls -ldF checkouts/*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 alan alan 17 May 12 13:57 checkouts/tupelo -> /home/alan/tupelo/
```

but uberjar fails:

```
~/expr/demo > lein clean ; lein uberjar
Compiling demo.core
Syntax error compiling at (demo/core.clj:6:3).
Syntax error compiling at (demo/core.clj:6:3).
Unable to resolve symbol: dummy-sample-data in this context

Full report at:
/tmp/clojure-10416346559924917196.edn
Compilation failed: Subprocess failed
```

---

**Options**

If you are wanting to deploy an application, you have 2 options:

1. If the lib exists on Clojars or Maven, you should probably deploy a release there before making a uberjar.  If the lib is not ready for Clojars or Maven, maybe you aren't ready to use it in a uberjar...?
2. Simply copy the source tree of `mylib` (or use a symlink!) under the `./src` dir in your project.  You'll also have to copy in the dependencies into `myproj/project.clj`.  You are effectively merging myproj and mylib, at least temporarily with this approach.  If the are coupled tightly enough to require co-development, perhaps it should be a permanent merge?

Comment: Thanks for your research. Unfortunately neither of those options looks very good. I'm making the uberjar to test the uberjar as part of my development. I'm trying to test something in Windows proper (but developing in WSL) so I need the Uberjar to be definitely outside the WSL environment. I don't want to permanently merge them though because the library is definitely used outside this context